# update element in the list of list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list of list and a list. I want to update the list of list by using the element from the second list.

For example:

I have a list of list
[[banan,NA],[apple,NA]] and a list [sweet,notsweet], 
want to update the list of the list, so I will have a list of list
[[banana,sweet],[apple,notsweet]]

I have tried the code below, but I think I cannot figured out the base case correctly.

```
update([[]],[],[]).
update([[T|_]|HH],[FB|H2],[NState|_]) :-
   NState=[T|FB],
   update(HH,H2,NState).
```

Any help, will be much appreciate

thanks

Comment: what is the query that you intend to try? `update( .... )` .... show it please inside your question. you can edit it.

Comment: not sure, I can find where to update my question, anyway here is my goal. I have list A =[[banana,_],[apple,_]] , list B=[sweet, notsweet], goal = [[banana,sweet],[apple,notsweet]]. ( use element of list 2 to update list2 and return the result after update.

Comment: under the question text, do you see the words "share   edit   flag" in grey? click on "edit" if you see it.

Comment: have you typed `list A =[[banana,*],[apple,*]] , list B=[sweet, notsweet], goal = [[banana,sweet],[apple,notsweet]]`? enclose your code in backticks ``"`"`` , otherwise a text between the `*`s shows up *in italics* (I typed `"*in italics*"`).

Comment: do you also envision calls like `A =[[*,banana,*,apple],[peach],[*,pepper]]` with `B=[sweet, salty, bitter, sour]`?

Comment: No, list a and b must be the same length, and also the sublist in list be must have 2 element fix.  for example [banana,sweet]

Comment: but the replacement position, is it fixed? always the 2nd?

Comment: yes, I just want it works in one direction only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. First let's observe that the first list is empty if there are no more `[fruit,*]` pairs left, hence the first argument of your base case should be `[]`. At that point the other lists have to be empty too, since they are of the same length.

In general, the first list will have a two-element list as its head, the first of which is being your object of interest and the second of which you don't care for, that is, something like `[X,_]`. The tail of that list will contain further `X`'s, so let's maybe call it `Xs`. Then the first argument looks like `[[X,_]|Xs]`. The second argument is a flat list, so you can write `[Y|Ys]` (read as: the list starts with a `Y` that is followed by further `Y`'s). The last argument is a two-element list `[X,Y]` that is followed by other such pairs (`XY`'s), hence: `[[X,Y]|XYs]`. The relation has to hold for the tails as well, that can be described by a recursive goal. You can express the above in Prolog like so:

```
update([],[],[]).
update([[X,_]|Xs],[Y|Ys],[[X,Y]|XYs]) :-
   update(Xs,Ys,XYs).
```

With these alterations to your predicate the example query from your comment yields the desired answer:

```
?- update([[banana,*],[apple,*]],[sweet,notsweet],C).
C = [[banana, sweet], [apple, notsweet]].
```